# How do I go about writing a parser?

Tags: c#, python, parsing

I have this giant Maude string. This is a small piece of it:

```
NamedElements
(    
    (
        NamedElement
        (
            SpecTable
            (
                 SpecColumns
                (

                    (
                        SpecColumn
                        (
                            Name
                            (
                                "Id"
                            )
                            ,
                             TypeVarChar
                            (
                                18
                            )

                        )
                        ,
                        SpecColumn
                        (
                            name
                            (
                                "IsDeleted"
                            )
                            ,
                                 DataTypeBit
                        )
```

...
...

There is only one thing called NamedElements. This has a lot of NamedElement objects in it. The format is simple to understand. I need to write a parser for this so that I can do something like get all SpecColumn objects who have a Name that is equal to something. I'm not sure the best way to do this though.

Some things i've thought about:

Loop through each character until I find a '('. I make a new object. I add this object as a property on the object above it. I continue going until I find the matching ')'. This then finalizes what's in that object.

Basically, I've never done anything like this before, and was wondering if there is some established way of doing this, or will I need to do something like what I described above?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parsing

Comment: Sorry, this question does not fit well Stack Overflow's scope, but here are some suggestions: 1. google "recursive descent parser", it's the easiest parsing technique, and you will find quite a lot of example implementations. 2. Have a look at the [overly simple JSON parser](https://github.com/H2CO3/libjsonz/tree/master/src/jsonz.c) I've written.

Comment: There are some excellent libraries available for this sort of thing, where you specify the grammar. An idea of language would be helpful to give more guidance, but boost spirit would be my recommendation for c++. Its also astonishingly fast.

Comment: I was planning to do this in either Python or C#.

Comment: If you want to use python, you might have a look at [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/)

Comment: Stop asking the same question [over](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19168216/does-a-maude-string-formatter-exist) and [over](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19188143/is-there-a-good-source-of-existing-parsers).

Answer (score 1):

To write a parser you need to define your grammar and syntax: the words you can use and how those words can be put together to make statements. This looks mostly like a markup for objects, similar to XML or JSON. But still, you need to define your language before you can write a parser.

In writing a parser, you should look at [lexical analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis). That's a good place to start. Once you know what is and is not in your language, you can then "parse" it, and convert it to whichever other thing you want, be it into another language, format, whatever.

Parsers consist of scanners, tokenizers, and a lexer. I know all of this is a bit vague, but your question is fairly open, as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you formalise the grammar a bit.

```
Name        ::= ( "STRING" )

TypeVarChar ::= ( NUMBER )

DataTypeBit ::= DATATYPEBIT

SpecColumn  ::= ( Name {, TypeVarChar | DataTypeBit} )

SpecColumns ::= ( SpecColumn {, SpecColumn}* )

SpecTable   ::= ( SpecColumns )
```

etc